# Elasticsearch query not returning anything

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have the following document indexed but when I run the search it's not returning anything, I was wondering if its an issue with the query. I am trying to search for any of the nested messages that have the word dogs in it. Here is the document:

```
{
"_index": "thread_and_messages",
"_type": "thread",
"_id": "3",
"_score": 1.0,
"_source": {
    "thread_id": 3,
    "thread_name": "I play the guitar",
    "created": "Wed Apr 13 2016",
    "thread_view": 2,
    "first_nick": "Test User",
    "messages": [{
        "message_text": " I like dogs",
        "message_id": 13,
        "message_nick": "Test"
    }],
    "site_name": "Test Site"
}
}
```

Here is the query I am running when I run the curl command:

```
{
"function_score": {
    "functions": [{
        "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "thread_view",
            "modifier": "log1p",
            "factor": 2
        }
    }],
    {"query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "match": {
                    "thread_name": "dogs"
                }
            }, {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "messages",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [{
                                "match": {
                                    "messages.message_text": "dogs"
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    },
                    "inner_hits": {}
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `messages.message_text` is an analyzed field?

Comment: I haven't defined whether this filed is analyzed or not, should I be defining it as analyzed?

Comment: Provide a output from : 
`curl -XGET localhost:9200/thread_and_messages/`

Comment: `{
 "thread_and_messages": {
  "aliases": {},
  "mappings": {
   "thread": {
    "properties": {
     "created": {
      "type": "string"
     },
     "first_nick": {
      "type": "string"
     },
     "messages": {
      "type": "nested",
      "include_in_parent": true,
      "properties": {
       "message_id": {
        "type": "string"
       },
       "message_nick": {
        "type": "string"
       },
       "message_text": {
        "type": "string"
       }
      }
     }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping you have plus the sample document with a slightly modified query works for me:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/thread_and_messages/thread/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "thread_view",
            "modifier": "log1p",
            "factor": 2
          }
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "thread_name": "dogs"
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "messages",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "should": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "messages.message_text": "dogs"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "inner_hits": {}
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```